# How to remove sas data set sort order efficiently?

Tags: sas

I have a sorted data set but want to remove the sort order flag (I don't want the users to expect the same order in the future).

`PROC DATASETS` can set the sort order, but I can't get it to set to nothing.

I tried:

```
PROC DATASETS lib=foo;
   /* Neither of these execute */
   modify bar(sortedby= );
   modify bar(sortedby=());
run;
```

I'm not seeing anything in the help center.

[SAS Help Center: DATASETS Procedure](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n0mfav25learpan1lerk79jsp30n.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting it to `_NULL_` is the way.

```
PROC DATASETS lib=foo;
    modify bar(sortedby=_NULL_);
Run;
```

Found the answer in another location:
[SAS Help Center: Syntax: PROC DATASETS MODIFY Statement](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n0ahh0eqtadmp3n1uwv55i2gyxiz.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)